# Calculating rate of return for multiple time frames (annualized, quarterly) with daily time series data (S&P 500 (SPX index) daily prices)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I have a CSV file with some 30 years worth of daily close prices for the [S&P 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_500) (SPX) stock market index, and I read it as Dataframe Series with Dates set as Index.

Dataframe:

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-13 | 3960.60 | 4003.95 | 3947.67 | 3999.09 |
| 2023-01-12 | 3977.57 | 3997.76 | 3937.56 | 3983.17 |
| 2023-01-11 | 3932.35 | 3970.07 | 3928.54 | 3969.61 |
| 2023-01-10 | 3888.57 | 3919.83 | 3877.29 | 3919.25 |
| 2023-01-09 | 3910.82 | 3950.57 | 3890.42 | 3892.09 |
| 1990-01-08 | 353.79 | 354.24 | 350.54 | 353.79 |
| 1990-01-05 | 352.20 | 355.67 | 351.35 | 352.20 |
| 1990-01-04 | 355.67 | 358.76 | 352.89 | 355.67 |
| 1990-01-03 | 358.76 | 360.59 | 357.89 | 358.76 |
| 1990-01-02 | 359.69 | 359.69 | 351.98 | 359.69 |

It effectively has a date (as index) column, and four columns (open, high, low, close) of daily prices. I am using *close* prices.

I would like a flexible function to calculate annual returns from the chosen start date to the end date using the formula:

```
(end_price / beginning_price - 1) * 100
```

So, the annual return for 2022 would be:

```
(SPX_Close_price_at_31_December_2022 - SPX_Close_price_at_31_December_2021 - 1)*100
```

It would be ideal if the same function could handle monthly or quarterly date inputs. Then, I would like these periodic returns (%) to be added to the dataframe in a separate column, and/or a new dataframe, and match the start and end dates across rows, so I can produce consecutive annual returns on a [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) line chart. And I would like to do this for the whole time series of 30 years.

This is the what I would like for the final dataframe to look like (return numbers below are examples only):

| Date | Annual Return (%) |
| --- | --- |
| m/d/2022 | -18 |
| m/d/2021 | 20 |
| m/d/2020 | 15 |
| m/d/2019 | 18 |

I am a beginner with Python am and still struggling working with date and datetime formats and matching those dates to data in columns across selected rows.

Below is what I got to so far, but it doesn't work properly. I will try the *dateutil* library, but I think that concepts of building out efficient functions is still something I need to work on. This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so thanks for having me :)

```
def spx_return(df, sdate, edate):

    delta = dt.timedelta(days=365)
    while (sdate <= edate):

        df2 = df['RoR'] = (df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift(-365) - 1) * 100

        sdate += delta
        #print(sdate, end="\n")

    return df2
```

Comment: Not sure why I can't upload an image of my source dataframe but it effectively has a date (as index) column, and 4 columns (open, high, low, close) of daily prices.

Comment: do you want the annual return for every single day or every single year?

Comment: Annual returns for every single year over the time series of 30 years.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Comment: There was some heroics which happened to save the day in this case (even though [they shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)).

Comment: I can appreciate that Peter. Will read through the link you attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate annual and quarterly rates in a generic way as well, I came up with a function that takes as arguments the start date, end date, and a pattern that distinguishes between years and quarters as the type of frequency. For the data frames extracted by start and end date, we use pd.Grouper() to extract the target data rows. For the result of that extraction, we will incorporate your formula in the next line. Also, when determining the rate from the start date, we need to go back further in time, so we subtract '366 days' or '90 days' for the frequency keyword. I have not verified that this value leads to the correct result in all cases. This is due to market holidays such as the year-end and New Year holidays. Setting a larger number of days may solve this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download("^GSPC", start="2016-01-01", end="2022-01-01")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)

def rating(data, startdate, enddate, freq):
    offset = '366 days' if freq == 'Y' else '90 days'
    #dff = df.loc[(df.index >= startdate) & (df.index <= enddate)]
    dff = df.loc[(df.index >= pd.Timestamp(startdate) - pd.Timedelta(offset)) & (df.index <= pd.Timestamp(enddate))]
    dfy = dff.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq=freq)).tail(1)
    ratio = (dfy['Close'] / dfy['Close'].shift()-1)*100
    return ratio
    
period_rating = rating(df, '2017-01-01', '2019-12-31', freq='Y')
print(period_rating)

Date
2016-12-30          NaN
2017-12-29    19.419966
2018-12-31    -6.237260
2019-12-31    28.878070
Name: Close, dtype: float64

period_rating = rating(df, '2017-01-01', '2019-12-31', freq='Q')
print(period_rating)

Date
2016-12-30          NaN
2017-03-31     5.533689
2017-06-30     2.568647
2017-09-29     3.959305
2017-12-29     6.122586
2018-03-29    -1.224561
2018-06-29     2.934639
2018-09-28     7.195851
2018-12-31   -13.971609
2019-03-29    13.066190
2019-06-28     3.787754
2019-09-30     1.189083
2019-12-31     8.534170
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

If your df has a `DatetimeIndex`, then you can use the `.loc` accessor with the date formatted as a string to retrieve the necessary values. For example, `df.loc['2022-12-31'].Close` should return the Close value on 2022-12-31.

In terms of efficiency, although you could use a shift operation, there isn't really a need to allocate more memory in a dataframe – you can use a loop instead:

```
annual_returns = []
end_dates = []
for year in range(1991,2022):
    end_date = f"{year}-12-31"
    start_date = f"{year-1}-12-31"
    end_dates.append(end_date)

    end_price, start_price = df.loc[end_date].Close, df.loc[start_date].Close
    annual_returns.append((end_price / start_price - 1)*100)
```

Then you can build your final dataframe from your lists:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(
    data=annual_returns,
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(end_dates, name='Date'),
    columns=['Annual Return (%)']
)
```

Using some sample data from `yfinance`, I get the following:

```
>>> df_final
            Annual Return (%)
Date
2008-12-31         -55.508475
2009-12-31         101.521206
2010-12-31          -4.195294
2013-12-31          58.431109
2014-12-31          -5.965609
2015-12-31          44.559938
2019-12-31          29.104585
2020-12-31          31.028712
2021-12-31          65.170561
```

Comment: With your first code cell I get a KeyError: Timestamp('1994-12-31 00:00:00'). '1994-12-31' was not a trading day so no data. If I try 30th of December for string format I get KeyError Timestamp('1990-12-30 00:00:00'). Again, not a trading day. Is there a library/module in Python that can skip to the next available date in the dataset?

Comment: you can use a loop to check the next available date, but which direction do you want to go in, and do you want the start date and end date to be exactly a year apart? what if `1994-12-29` is a trading date, but `1993-12-29` isn't? if you don't need to be exact, then it might be simplest to take the first and last day of a particular calendar year

Comment: Start and end dates don't have to be exactly one year apart.  For example, return for 1994 year would be (price on 30/12/1994 / price on 03/01/1994 -1). Question is really about how to skip to next available but descending date in the dataset. So, if I want to calculate the return from 26 January 2023 to approximately the same date last year, how would I find the first available descending trading date if 26/01/2022 is not available in the data set.  Not sure how to use a loop to get to that and integrate it in a way that solves the overall coding problem (getting a df with periodic returns).

Comment: @maikoh definitely a bit of work, but probably should be possible with a loop. i would likely need to rework my solution to use datetime objects though because if you have a start date of 01/01/1993 and the end date of 01/01/1994 isn't available, then we need to check 31/12/1993 next and a datetime object is ideal for that. i'll update my solution later when i'm off work